# Is there a HTML test file I can use for CSS resets?

Tags: html, css, css-reset

There are a lot of [CSS resets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/). I am building something for mobile devices and I want to skip as much of the unnecessary CSS as possible so I was wondering if there is an [exhaustive HTML test page](http://snipplr.com/view/8121/html-test-page-for-css-style-guide/) I can run some of the [CSS resets](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/10/23/a-killer-collection-of-global-css-reset-styles/) against to test them?

Testing the rules is also a great way to learn what edge cases are required, what they target, and why.

Comment: What's wrong with the one you linked to?

Comment: @Jan It is very small and only covers some of the most basic elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around today I finally found a awesome site called http://cssresetr.com/ which offers you a chance to test a fairly-large set of stylesheets on many deferent groups of elements!

I can probably just steal the HTML for each group and mash it up into a single page - then try some of the stylesheets not listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly skip any tags in your reset that *you know you will not be using*. For example, if you never use definition lists, skip the *dl*, *dt* and *dd* resets.

Remember, **a CSS reset is simply a starting point**, so you can be reasonably sure your page looks the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the one supplied by YUI ?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/reset/reset-simple_source.html